# What is the meaning of following syntax? (objective-c style method call)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ios5

I'm a noob in objective-c (from C#/Java background), and have difficulty understanding following objective-c syntax, which is used in `Picker View` control(and also other methods we need to implement for using `Picker View`):

```
-(NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row 
             forComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

In order to understand, I tried to map it to the following syntax, but seems to be totally different.

```
-(NSString *)MethodName: (UIPickerView *)FirstParam and:(NSInteger)SecondParam 
             and:(NSInteger)ThirdParam
```

Could someone decompose the parts and give some explanation please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a method named

`pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`

It returns a pointer to a `NSString`, and requires parameters of types UIPickerView*, NSInteger, and NSInteger.

A java-like method declaration might look like this:

`NSString pickerViewTitleForRowForComponent(UIPickerView pickerView, NSInteger row, NSInteger component)`

Answer (score 5):

The difference is that in Objective-C the method name is composed of parts, and not a single string as in java.

```
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row ...
/*    ^           ^             ^            ^          ^            
      |           |             |            |          |            
  Return Type     |       Argument Type      | 2nd part of m. name     etc....
                  |                          |
         Part of method name           Argument Name
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

...erik aligner and bdares answers explain all

just one more thing:

the "-" minus letter at the beginning means that you can call this method with an instance of the class.
in this case the method is called by the pickerView itself (you don't call it, you just implement it in a class which adopts the UIPickerViewDelegate Protocol / meaning it use all methods required by that protocol )

but, in general, methods that start with minus sign should be called on instances.
for example, the method

```
- (void)addSubview:(UIView *)view
```

declared in UIViewClass, should be called this way:

```
[yourUIViewInstance addSubview:yourSubViewInstance];
```

while methods declared with a plus "+" sign mean that you need to call them not on instance (you may have not any instance allocated at all) but on the class itself

for example, for UIView method

```
+ (void)setAnimationDelay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
```

you should call it this way:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelay:1.0];
```

Answer (score 1):

The method name (selector) is all three components: `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:`. Aside from that, you have it exactly right. (Yes, arguments and selector segments are mixed together in Objective-C. This is one of its strengths; it aids readability of long message expressions.)